# Winrar sfx command line add file details

Tags: command-line, winrar, self-extracting

I have a winrar command similar to this one to bundle some exes.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -sfx -iicon"logo.ico" -k -z"options_notepad.txt" "Export\notepadPack.exe" "notepad.exe"
```

options_notepad.txt

```
Setup=notepad.exe
TempMode
Silent=1
Overwrite=1
```

I would like to add add informations like copyright or the file version to my sfx. I'm using winrar 4.20.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [go-winres](https://github.com/tc-hib/go-winres/releases/tag/v0.1.0):

- Run `go-winres init` to create a `winres`directory
- In `winres\winres.json`:

  - Delete the parts named `"RT_MANIFEST"` and `"RT_GROUP_ICON"`
  - Fill the fields in the remaining part named `"RT_VERSION"` (leave `"#1"` and `"0000"` as is)
- Run `go-winres patch yourarchive.exe`
- Once you have checked everything is alright, delete `yourarchive.exe.bak`.

Example `winres.json`:

```
{
  "RT_VERSION": {
    "#1": {
      "0000": {
        "fixed": {
          "file_version": "1.2.3.0"
        },
        "info": {
          "0409": {
            "FileDescription": "A fabulous archive",
            "LegalCopyright": "© Philipp H."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to edit it as utf-8.